# MYSQL ON DELETE CASCADE - Only works when set on a primary key

Tags: mysql, database, cascade

I have been facing to an issue with `ON DELETE CASCADE` in MySQL. It works perfectly when it is set on a *primary key* field, but not in other cases.

---

For example, I have a **child table** where I have a foreign key referring to a field in the **parent table**, but the **child table** has its own *Auto-Incremental* ID field which needs to be a primary key because **grandchildren tables** refer to it.

When I delete a row from the parent table, all records disappear as expected and no errors appear, however, the child's data depending on the deleted row of the parent table stays untouched.

I made researches without results. Although I assume it is something to do with the system identifying a row by its primary key, I could not find any relevant info about this.

The parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_parent (
            ID              TINYINT(3)    UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `level`         TINYINT(1)    NOT NULL,
            updated         DATETIME      NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
        );
```

The child table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_child (
            ID              TINYINT(3)    UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            parentId        TINYINT(3)    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            `name`          VARCHAR(16)   UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            updated         DATETIME      NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
        );
```

The relation:

```
ALTER TABLE table_child
        ADD FOREIGN KEY (parentId)        REFERENCES table_parent(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

And in a nutshell, my goal would be to delete all records in table_child table where the parentId equals to the deleted row in table_parent.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that what you are missing is that referential integrity constraints only work with InnoDB tables.  Your DDL statements are missing the `engine=InnoDB` and most likely are defaulting to MyISAM.

While you will not receive an error on the declarations, MyISAM tables are by default what you get when you don't specify an engine, and MyISAM ignores constraint statements.

A corrected CREATE TABLE statement would be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_parent (
        ID              TINYINT(3)    UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `level`         TINYINT(1)    NOT NULL,
         updated         DATETIME      NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

[Here's a SQL Sandbox](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5zMb1ZTwqUgixn1tPCRQdj/3) demonstrating that the constraint is correct and works as you expect it to.

This is not relevant to the question, but it seems odd to me that you declared all your keys to be TINYINTs.  That would mean that you could have a maximum of 255 rows in your tables....

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your effort. I have tried it before - and now again -, but unfortunately it does not work still.

Regarding the _TINYINT_ fields, I need to store around 200 (+-30) rows only in this table and I try to use as less space as possible, so I thought _TINYINT_ would be appropriate

Comment: **UPDATE**: I reinstalled the whole database multiple times using the `ENGINE=InnoDB` statements, now it looks like the problem is solved - it did not work because I also use GULP to compile and arrange files, and the process was killed by an error there. So, thank you @gview for your answer, it solved the issue :)

Comment: If you only need that small number of rows, then an unsigned tinyint is perfect.  Just be aware that your auto_increment will continue to increase and exceed 255 even if you delete all the rows from the table.  You can reset the auto_increment, but that would only be appropriate if you are indeed planning to delete all the rows at certain points and start with a fresh set of values.